# export Oracle DB schema in H2 format with liquibase. Difference between `sql` and `xml` outputs

Tags: oracle, h2, liquibase, liquibase-maven-plugin

I'm exporting a Oracle schema, and I want to have a script that I can use for in-memory tests  with H2.

I export the schema with maven, `mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog`.

I have noticed that when I specify an `outputChangeLogFile` of type `sql`, the Oracle and H2 formats produce different output (e.g. `generatedChangelog.h2.sql` vs `generatedChangelog.oracle.sql`).

With type `xml` they produce the same ( `generatedChangelog.h2.xml` vs `generatedChangelog.oracle.xml`).

In particular, with the `sql` type I get

- `NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL` for H2
- `NAME VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) NOT NULL` for Oracle

with the `xml` format I get

- `<column name="NAME" type="VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)">` for both H2 and Oracle

this particular syntax is not valid with H2, so this seems a bug to me. Liquibase can clearly understands this as you can see from the `sql` example, but it doesn't produce a valid `changeSet` for the `xml` format.

Is there anything I can do to produce the correct output in `xml` format?

Thanks

Comment: You can also report this as a bug here: https://www.liquibase.org/community/contribute/report-bugs

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a lot of differences between different databases. What you can do (manually or by some regex) is to create changeLog variables and do following:

- change column definition

```xml
<column name="NAME" type="VARCHAR2(255${byteType})">
```

- add variable for different db vendors

```xml
<property name="byteType" dbms="oracle" value="BYTE"/>
<property name="byteType" dbms="h2" value=""/>
```

with changes above you'll be able to run changeSets against both (or almost any) databases.